# View Name with @ sign | not able to go inside to get describe

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

[image]

there is a view as above. but i cannot get inside of it. but when i write the select, it give me the data and ask for commit or rollback
[image]

My issue is that Actual cost is wrong. SO i need to correct it. but not able to go inside and see what is happening there.

Do you guys have any idea of what is this '@' sign and why it is not allow to inside?
why it ask for commit?

Oracle says that it is possible to crate table name with '@' sign. but this is not it.

I am using PL/SQL developer

Guidance ? :)

Comment: Please post the sql statement as text in your question, not picks we are hard to read.

Comment: Usually @ used in dblinks ( to access to another server) maybe thats why you are not able to access it. because this view in another database. this query select * from dba_db_links shows if you have any dblinks

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @Moudiz SQL query help to list down all the links with the database but need to be logged into the database as 'sys' user. it works and those links has all the connection details as you are reading 'tnsnames.ora' file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it happens when selecting from a view via a database link.

This is why: Controlling connections established by database links (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_appdev002.htm#ADMIN12194):

> When a global object name is referenced in a SQL statement or remote
>   procedure call, database links establish a connection to a session in
>   the remote database on behalf of the local user. The remote connection
>   and session are only created if the connection has not already been
>   established previously for the local user session.
>
> The connections and sessions established to remote databases persist
>   for the duration of the local user's session, unless the application
>   or user explicitly terminates them. Note that when you issue a SELECT
>   statement across a database link, a transaction lock is placed on the
>   undo segments. To rerelease the segment, you must issue a COMMIT or
>   ROLLBACK statement.

As you're just *selecting*, it doesn't really matter whether you'll rollback or commit (I push the *rollback* button). After that, recreate the view so that it calculates the correct value you've mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot. My confusions are solved. I found the correct view by referring to link.   I was able to list down the links by using  Moudiz's SQL query but have to login to the database as sys user.